# Advantages of Using MethodType in Python

Tags: python, oop, methods, monkeypatching

What are the advantages of using `MethodType` from the `types` module? You can use it to add methods to an object. But we can do that easily without it:

```
def func():
   print 1

class A:
   pass

obj = A()
obj.func = func
```

It works even if we delete `func` in the main scope by running `del func`.

Why would one want to use `MethodType`? Is it just a convention or a good programming habit?

Comment: That's not really adding a method to `obj` though. `obj.func()` is the same as calling just `func()`. A method receives the instance as the 1. positional argument. You could create a bound method with `func.__get__(obj, A)`, but that wouldn't work either, since `func` takes no arguments.

Comment: Your function `func` does not have a `self` argument. You use `type` when you want to attach or replace a *method* of a class. Here you are just attaching a *function* to a class..

Answer (score 62, accepted):

In fact the difference between adding methods dynamically at run time and
your example is huge:

- in your case, you just attach a function to an object, you can call it of course but it is *unbound*, it has no relation with the object itself (ie. you cannot use `self` inside the function)
- when added with `MethodType`, you create a *bound* method and it behaves like a normal Python method for the object, you *have to* take the object it belongs to as first argument (it is normally called `self`) and you can access it inside the function

This example shows the difference:

```
def func(obj):
  print 'I am called from', obj
class A:
  pass
a=A()
a.func=func
a.func()
```

This fails with a `TypeError`: `func() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)`,
whereas this code works as expected:

```
import types
a.func = types.MethodType(func, a) # or types.MethodType(func, a, A) for PY2
a.func()
```

shows `I am called from <__main__.A instance at xxx>`.

Comment: So in short it means I would not be able to use attributes of object that I used this upon. For example if there was an attribute let's say `att` in my definition then I would not be able to use it right?

Comment: In your case in your question, the function is decoupled from the object. There is no way to access the object from the function because the function is not a method at all.

Comment: @ABHI no, `att` can be accessed from anywhere, but you need an instance of the class to access it on (i.e. `att` by itself doesn't mean anything, you need `obj.att`). Methods defined normally (and are therefore bound) get the `self`argument which is the instance that the method is bound to and so they have an easy way to get to the appropriate `att`.

Comment: Note that in Python 3 `types.MethodType` only takes two arguments, so for this example the call is `types.MethodType(func, a)`

Answer (score 7):

A common use of `types.MethodType` is checking whether some object is a method.  For example:

```
>>> import types
>>> class A(object):
...     def method(self):
...         pass
...
>>> isinstance(A().method, types.MethodType)
True
>>> def nonmethod():
...     pass
...
>>> isinstance(nonmethod, types.MethodType)
False
```

Note that in your example `isinstance(obj.func, types.MethodType)` returns `False`.  Imagine you have defined a method `meth` in class `A`.  `isinstance(obj.meth, types.MethodType)` would return `True`.